# How do you change the value a timer sends on the Time Expired Ping in Rec Room?

Tags: rec-room

I am studying incremental games and I would like to know how to change the signal from a timer from 1 to whatever I want it to be.

For example if a player buys and upgrade how can I change my signal every second to reflect that change?

Comment: if your question have been answered, please accept them, otherwise leave a comment on the answer what you are missing. Same for all of your questions on Arqade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Timer Expired pin from a timer will always output a 1, so to change it you need additional logic built around the Timer Chip.

Use a comparator as a gate that checks for when the timer expired pin fires (i.e. is not 0). When that happens, the value through the cyan pin (depicted as blue in this image) will be passed through to the red output pin. In all other cases the value through the magenta pin (depicted as cyan in this image) will be passed through to the green output pin.

[image: Comparator Based Gate]

With this logic you can have a baseline value that is present when the timer has not expired and then a different value pulsed when the timer does expire. You can remove the plus chip and then just use the red output if your baseline value is just 0.

Comment: I think we should avoid advising people to use multipliers as gates. Advanced comparers can do the same thing, but are safer. I would also always advise to use ≠ comparisons, because in general, they are safer. Building circuits is a lot about habits, so we should try to convey good habits here. By "good habits" here I mean habits that don't backfire when used in a different context without thinking (multipliers or `>` can easily backfire).

Comment: You're right, I've updated the answer appropriately.

Comment: Thx. I also re-read the question again, and he is also asking about modification of a timer output modification per player, which this answer skips. There are probably no good ways to do that, but the answer should at least acknowledge that.